# Deadlock in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I got deadlock while performing several queries parallely in pgsql. It throws the exception as

```
  Detail: Process 6656 waits for ShareLock on transaction 609600; blocked by process 8616.
  Process 8616 waits for ShareLock on transaction 609603; blocked by process 6656.
  Hint: See server log for query details.
```

Here how can I find which process (query) is 6656?

Comment: Check the results from this query: SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your pgsql version >= 9.2, the locking query would be there

```
select * from pg_stat_activity where pid=6656
```

In case your pgsql version < 9.2, the locking query would not be there

```
select * from pg_stat_activity where procpid=6656
```

In order to kill the process

```
select pg_terminate_backend(pid_to_kill);
```

or

```
select pg_cancel_backend(pid_to_cancel);
```

I'd rather recommend that you do `pg_cancel_backend` instead of `pg_terminate_backend` as the first choice if you are using `PGPOOL`.